# qui était lui aussi très distant -- how do you understand "lui" as used in this passage?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, emphase

Quote:

> Je comprends mieux maintenant la réaction de son petit
>   ami qui était **lui** aussi très distant.

To me, the sentence makes perfect sense without that *lui* there: *who was also very distant*. But why do we need it there? What purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "lui" is not necessary, but it goes with the "aussi" to give more emphasis on the person, and it is better like this.  I know it doesn't translate like this in English, but it would be something like "him too". The meaning is that she was very distant, and her boyfriend was also very distant. If you just say "aussi", there would be some ambiguity about the the "addition" in the sentence (it could be adding a person (in this case, the boyfriend) or it could be adding an adjective (we already know that the boyfriend was shy, then we learn that he is also very distant)).

Answer (score 2):

The content of this answer is essentially that in user **[radouxju](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/34835/17649)**, but I thought that some précisions and rewording would be useful.

This is one instance of a general construction;

- moi aussi, toi aussi, lui/elle/ça/cela aussi, nous aussi, vous aussi, ils/elles/eux/ceux-là  aussi

It is used to associate someone or a group to someone else or to an another group in the way of specifying they have the same characteristic, attitude, behaviour, opinions, etc. Besides persons, things can also be the elements put on the level of an association this way. It is necessary in certain constructions in order to preserve a good style, that is, in the present case, in order to remain entirely unambiguous as to what is being intended, whether association to a group already mentioned or compounding of characteristics. Moreover, even when there does not exist a blatant context of ambiguity, it is used to remove any doubt that could remain in the interlocutor's mind: this  is so because the adverb the syntax of "aussi" carries inherently some vagueness as to which element it bears upon in the sentence or said otherwise, as to which element it is connected to. However it is not always necessary to use this construction; whether to use it or not depends on the whole construction.
In the instance of the question, it is necessary but let's look at the following examples;

- Je comprends mieux maintenant la réaction de son petit ami, Jean; il était lui aussi très distant.
- Je comprends mieux maintenant la réaction de son petit ami, Jean; Jean aussi était très distant.

Nevertheless, in this last example, where we can do away with the added  pronoun, it is not considered as bad style to emphasise the association by using it and there are three possibilities.

- Je comprends mieux maintenant la réaction de Jean, son petit ami; Jean, **lui aussi**,  était  très distant. *There is no certitude as to whether there should be commas around "lui aussi", but I'd rather use them.*
- … ; Jean  était **lui aussi**  très distant.
- … ; Jean  était très distant, **lui aussi**.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Révision : ma réponse précédente n'est pas idéale, essentiellement à cause de mes lacunes en français.</sub>

> Je comprends mieux maintenant la réaction de son petit ami qui était lui aussi très distant.

La phrase est composée d'une proposition principale et d'une proposition subordonnée relative. La subordonnée relative complète normalement le groupe nominal principal. En outre, le complément du nom est subordonné au nom. Le pronom personnel « lui » remplace le pronom relatif « qui » dans la fonction de sujet de la proposition subordonnée relative. On pourrait dire « Lui aussi était très distant ». En conséquence, le locuteur précise que les personnes qu'il évoque sont « très distante(s) » et il informe le(s) interlocuteur(s) qu'il comprend la réaction « (du) petit ami ». Néanmoins, on ne saisit pas vraiment le lien qui existe entre « la réaction (du) petit ami » et l'état « distant » des personnes auquel fait référence le locuteur. Cette phrase n'est pas claire. Par conséquent, il aurait mieux valu l'exprimer autrement.

> Je comprends mieux maintenant la réaction de son petit ami ; lui aussi était très distant.

La phrase ci-dessus est intelligible : les groupes fonctionnels sont apparant, les deux propositions sont subséquentes et clairement structurées.